# "Extra Argument in Call" Error when calling WKInterfaceLabel.setText

Tags: swift, watchkit

I am currently trying to make an altimeter for a project, but I am stumped on this "Extra Argument in Call" error, and after researching for about 4 hours have not been able to find anything in particular to help me.

I did see, however, that this error can be misleading and that there's not something wrong with the call and that it's a problem with something else. Me and my peers are stumped on this error and have turned here to see if we could possibly get help here.

I got my base code from Joel Crabb (http://joelcrabb.com/?p=289) and it has ended up like this after updating a bit of his outdated code.

Below is my Interface controller

```
//
//  AltitudeInterfaceController.swift
//  lets learn WatchKit Extension
//
//  Created by M.McCoy on 1/24/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 M.McCoy All rights reserved.
//

import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

class AltitudeInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


    //source: Joel Crabb: http://joelcrabb.com/?p=289

    @IBOutlet var altitudeLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
    lazy var altimeter = CMAltimeter()
    lazy var queue = OperationQueue()
    var relativeAltitude = 0
    @IBAction func startButton(){
        if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable()
        {
        
            altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdates(to: queue, withHandler: {(data: CMAltitudeData?, error: NSError?) in
            
                //Needed to refresh the screen from inside the closure
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.altitudeLabel.setText("%.2f feet",
                      ((3.28 * //Extra argument in call error here.
                        ((data?.relativeAltitude.doubleValue))!)))
                };
        })
         }   else {
                 self.altitudeLabel.setText("No barometer available")
         }
       }
```

Thank you in advance for helping and explaining what I need to do to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

SetText has only one parameter and it is string. I know that you want to pass a double value with format number, but that is not the way.

Try this:

```
self.altitudeLabel.setText(String(format:"average temp. = %.2f", 3.28 *data?.relativeAltitude.doubleValue!))
```